# Rails 3 - Does ID of an object have to be an integer value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

**C:\Rails\actuirl5\app\controllers\emailinterests_controller.rb**

**C:\Rails\actuirl5\app\controllers\emailinterests_controller.rb**

submission_id actually a member of emailinterest object. submission_id is suppose to contain the ID value of submission object.

```
def create
    @emailinterest = Emailinterest.new(params[:emailinterest])
    @submission = Submission.find(params[:submission_id])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @emailinterest.save
            Notifier.emailinterest_notification(@emailinterest, @submission).deliver
            format.html { redirect_to(@emailinterest, :notice => 'Email was successfully sent!') }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @emailinterest, :status => :created, :location => @emailinterest }
        else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @emailinterest.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

I keep getting stuck at this line

```
@submission = Submission.find(params[:submission_id])
```

with this error.

```
Couldn't find Submission without an ID
```

---

Submission and Emailinterest are both objects.

Emailinterest need some information about the members of the Submission object to be created.

submission_id actually a member of Emailinterest object. submission_id is suppose to contain the ID value of Submission object.

Now I have submission_id as string value. Does it have to be an integer value?

---

## FIX

**C:\Rails\actuirl5\app\controllers\emailinterests_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @emailinterest = Emailinterest.new(params[:emailinterest])
    @submission = Submission.find(params[:submission_id])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @emailinterest.save
            Notifier.emailinterest_notification(@emailinterest, @submission).deliver
            format.html { redirect_to(@emailinterest, :notice => 'Email was successfully sent!') }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @emailinterest, :status => :created, :location => @emailinterest }
        else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @emailinterest.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

**C:\Rails\actuirl5\app\views\submissions_form_new_emailinterest.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(emailinterest) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :submission_id, value = @submission.id %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :sender_email %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :sender_email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :sender_email_content %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :sender_email_content %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**C:\Rails\actuirl5\app\views\submissions\show.html.erb**

```
<%= render :partial=>"form_new_emailinterest", :locals=>{:emailinterest=>Emailinterest.new} %>
```

Comment: It don't have to be integer. Method find(value) can take string (it probably cast value to integer later). What is the exact value of 'params[:emailinterest][:submission_id]'? Are you sure that this value is not blank?

Comment: Im not sure how to check that value. However, it's suppose to have the value of **submission.id**. I do this in   <%= hidden_field :submission_id %> in view file.

Comment: please put line 'throw params[:emailinterest][:submission_id]' at the first line of create function. Then try to create ;)

Comment: Add a `logger.info params.inspect` to your controller and look in your logs, `:submission_id` might not be where you think it is.

Comment: I changed from `params[:emailinterest][:submission_id]` to `params[:submission_id]`. `throw params[:submission_id]` shows `uncaught throw {"{:value"=>">4}]="}`. This is interesting because **4** should be the intended value of the submission_id I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error:

> Couldn't find Submission without an ID

is probably caused by

```
@submission = Submission.find(nil)
```

and `nil` is what a Hash will give when you ask it for a key it doesn't have (unless someone has supplied a different default of course but `params` and its contained Hashes should give you `nil`). So you don't have a `:submission_id` inside `params[:emailinterest]`. Based on your comments, I would guess that you do have `params[:submission_id]` so try this:

```
@submission = Submission.find(params[:submission_id])
```

and if that doesn't work, do a `logger.debug params.inspect` and look at your logs to see where `:submission_id` is (if anywhere at all).

Comment: I changed from `params[:emailinterest][:submission_id]` to `params[:submission_id]`. `throw params[:submission_id]` shows `uncaught throw {"{:value"=>">4}]="}`. This is interesting because **4** should be the intended value of the submission_id I am using. I don't know why `@submission = Submission.find(params[:submission_id])` still says `Couldn't find Submission with ID=`

Comment: @garbage collection: Please include the `logger.debug params.inspect` output in your question, `{"{:value"=>">4}]="}` looks a bit muddled.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a string or anything, as long as it can be converted to an integer.

You can verify this using your rails console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Product.find("1")
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
 => #<Product id: 1, collection_id: nil, name: "test", description: nil, price: 1000, picture_file_name: nil, picture_content_type: nil, picture_file_size: nil, picture_updated_at: nil, created_at: "2011-07-14 10:10:45", updated_at: "2011-07-14 10:10:45">
```

If you want to know what's really in `submission_id`, you can log the value by putting this at the beginning of your method:

```
logger.debug params[:emailinterest][:submission_id]
```